# pushing values from json into array

Tags: angularjs, json

JSON:

```
 var res =   
         {
          "response": {
            "data": {
              "profilesearchsnippet": [
                [
                  {
                    "profileInfo": {
                      "firstname": "Sundar",
                      "lastname": "v",
                      "gender": "male",
                      "country": "Afghanistan",
                      "state": "Badakhshan",
                      "city": "Eshkashem",
                      "pincode": "",
                      "plancode": "T001",
                      "userid": 13
                    },
                    "roleInfo": {
                      "defaultphotoid": 94
                    }
                  }
                ],
                [
                  {
                    "profileInfo": {
                      "firstname": "ghg",
                      "lastname": "vbhvh",
                      "gender": "male",
                      "state": "Badakhshan",
                      "city": "Eshkashem",
                      "pincode": "454",
                      "plancode": "T001",
                      "userid": 22
                    },
                    "roleInfo": {
                      "defaultphotoid": 171
                    }
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

In the above json , I need to move `roleInfo.defaultphotoid` into `var image`

JS:

```
$scope.setimage = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet[0];
  for (var i = 0; i++; i<setimage.length; i++){
  var image = [];
  image .push(setimage[i].roleinfo.defaultphotoid);
   }
```

I assigned one variable named setimage and from there I am trying to push values of all defaultphotoid in another array image to fetch images of all roleinfos, but I am able to fetch only first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `var image = []` is inside the for loop. It gets re-initialized after every cycle. You need to put it outside the loop

```
$scope.setimage = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet[0];
var image = [];
for (var i = 0; i<$scope.setimage.length; i++){
    image.push($scope.setimage[i].roleinfo.defaultphotoid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use angular.foreach inorder to iterate the elements and set into the variable.

```
var log = [];
angular.forEach(res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet[0], function(value, key) {
  this.push(setimage[i].roleinfo.defaultphotoid);
}, log);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.setimage = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;
var images = [];

for (var i = 0; i<$scope.setimage.length; i++){
  image.push($scope.setimage[i][0].roleinfo.defaultphotoid);
}
```

will work.